# Is adding a mobile number compulsory for creating a twitter app?

Tags: twitter

I want to create a twitter app but twitter is not allowing me to do so and asking to add a mobile number to my profile before creating the app. Earlier I used to successfully create the apps without entering any mobile number.  Has twitter made mobile number adding compulsory for creating an app?

Comment: Yes mobile number compulsory for creating a twitter app. http://sgeek.org/how-to-create-twitter-app-in-4-easy-steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like they have..

I tested it with my account and I'm getting the same message (to first add my mobile number before I'm able to complete the creation of a new app..)

Also some others have the same probs.. 
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/25637